# How can I export transactions from GnuCash including references to associated files

Tags: gnucash

I can add files to transactions using menu

```
Transaction > associate file with transaction to assign files.
```

I want to export the transactions in a way so that this file reference it included in the exported file.

I'm using GnuCash 2.6.13 on Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file association feature is new to gnucash, and will not be fully supported until 2018 ([link](https://gnucash.uservoice.com/forums/101223-feature-request/suggestions/5333803-file-linkage-to-transaction)).

I have had success using the python bindings in gnucash to accomplish tasks which are not supported through the user interface ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055318/create-transaction-in-gnucash-in-response-to-an-email/22338982#22338982)), so if you know or would like to learn some python coding, that might solve your problem.